# Thumbnail images are not loading Magento 2.3.0

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, product-images, catalog, porto-theme

On **Category Listing Page** my **Product Thumbnail** Images are not Loading whenever I apply a **Filter** on to the Category Page or I try to Navigate to some other pages of the Category. The first page of the category Loads fine and shows the Thumbnail Images without any issues.

I am using Porto Theme....

This is what I get on category listing page:

[image]

My Console Shows this:

[image]

Any help would be appreciated..

I also tried using this command but no Luck:

```
 php bin/magento catalog:images:resize
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this command:

`php bin/magento catalog:images:resize`

`php bin/magento cache:flush`

***update:***
please check this:

```
Category View
In this tab, you can set options for the category view page.

Show Alternative Product Image: When you mouse hover on a product, you can see a thumbnail image. You can enable/disable this function in this option.

Keep Image Aspect Ratio: If set to Yes, shows product image with uploaded image's size ratio.

Keep Image Aspect Ratio - Yes
```

Cheers

Comment: I tried that already but still no Luck :(

Comment: hi, version of porto theme?

Comment: The Version of Porto Theme is 3.1.7